# Entity Framework 6 - DataReader keeps connection open

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have a DB table with `~50k` rows

```
ad_group_id (int)
ad_group_name (varchar(1024))
```

I try to fetch all the rows like this:

```
var adgroups = _ctx.[MY TABLE].SqlQuery(@"select ad_group_id, ad_group_name from [SB_SCHEMA].bckoff_ad_groups_lkp").AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

These are the logs:

```
select ad_group_id, ad_group_name from [MY_TABLE]

-- Executing at 11/17/2019 6:48:14 PM +02:00

-- Completed in 153 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Closed connection at 11/17/2019 6:48:37 PM +02:00
```

As you can see, even though the query is pretty fast, the connection is being kept open for around 23 seconds.

When I select only the ad_group_id column, it takes 2 seconds, but when I add the ad_group_name column to the select statement, it jumps to 23 seconds

I assume it's the time it takes for the DataReader to fetch the data.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you explicitly disposing the context _ctx?

Comment: You have IoC for your context? Otherwise, as mnieto says you need to dispose such as wrapping it in a `using`.

Comment: It's a web web api with a single instance of dbcontext, but I also tested it inside a using clause, and still, same result

Comment: OK, your title is misleading. The connection is closing, but you are concerned with the performance. Have you tried the same queries is SSMS?